# If I push an object underwater, how long before it stops?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, projectile, drag

If I were to push an object that is completely submerged in water with a know force, how would I go about finding the distance it travels before coming to a stop given that I know the drag coefficient of the object?
I would like to know if this is possible using simple equation or maybe through CFD?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically no different than pushing/throwing and object in free air. Forces like buoyancy and drag will just be different.

- There will be a fluid resistance or **drag** force $D$ always antiparallel to the velocity direction, which can be expressed as something like $$D=\frac 12 C_DA\rho v^2$$
  with $C_D$ being the drag coefficient, $A$ the cross-section area of the perpendicular surface, $v$ the speed and $\rho$ the fluid density. $C_D$ can often be a challenge to know reliably, and you may have to go for a Reynolds number estimation ([see more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics))).
- There will also be a much more significant upwards **buoyancy** force $B$, though. This force is also present in air, but insignificant. It can be found with 
  $$B=V\rho g$$
  with $V$ being the displaced volume (the object volume plus any unfilled cavities) and $g$ the gravitational constant.
- Apart from these, the object of course always has a **weight** $w=mg$.

Now that we have all forces under control, then simply set up Newton's 2nd law by summing up all forces vertically and horizontally. Distance, speed and acceleration are all related as integrals/differentiations of each other, so it should be possible to go backwards to distance from some of the involved parameters. Also, you will have to know - or estimate - the initial speed that you have given the object in the moment that you stopped pushing.

It can be a bit tricky since some forces depend on other parameters that change over time, such as $D$ that depends on $v$ (and also has a non-constant angle), and $\rho$ that, depending on the depth, can change with depth. This is why you must use integration and not one of the usual constant-acceleration motion equations .

Comment: is it correct to use V d g for buoyant force, since the case is dynamic rather than static? (d for density)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Right now I am working on it like a friction problem, with drag force inducing a negative acceleration. But as you mentioned drag force is dependent on the velocity of the object hence it has to be recalculated as time varies. I am writing a Matlab code in hopes of getting this solved.

Comment: How is this pushing force? It acts all the time or is just a short push providing some initial momentum?

Comment: @nasu I believe we are dealing with an object being thrown. The motion and forces I have described in this answer deal with the path that the object follows from the moment the object leaves your hand.

Comment: @Steeven Sorry, the comment was meant for the OP. I added it at the end of your question by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It will go down as long as the sum of gravity and force you exerted `F = ma`, equals the sum of buoyancy force and drag of the object and water. The moment these are equal is stops and the buoyancy will push the object upwards. This is the case when the density of the object is lower than water. If the density is higher, the object decelerates by the drag and then the gravity will push it downwards winning over the buoyancy, however, due to higher buoyancy of water compared to air it falls much slower than when you drop it outside water.